# "Or" procedure in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm doing a prolog program for college that is a bit like the cluedo game. I have six suspects with different traits:

```
suspect(Name, Age, Weapon, Shape, Object, Shoes)
```

The goal is to implement a series of clues so that the program says which the different traits of all the six suspects. For example:

```
suspect(Hannibal Lecter,67,knife,'in good shape',mac,'high heels')
```

I'm having problems trying to implement the clue

```
or(suspect1, suspect2, suspect3, listOfSuspects)
```

This clue is supposed to say that the `suspect1` has the same traits as `suspect2` OR as `suspect3` but not both. Example: To indicate that the suspect who is 50 years old has a ring or a mac, but not both:

```
or(suspect(_, 50, _, _, _, _),
   suspect(_, _, _, _, ring, _),
   suspect(_, _, _, _, mac, _), listOfSuspects).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `findall`. You do know why to get a disjunction in Prolog, right?

Comment: @Iarsmans I'm not seeing how I would use findall in the implementation of this clue. I was trying to think of a way to "merge" suspect1 with suspect2 or suspect1 with suspect3. I'm sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I'm feeling a bit clueless...

Comment: It would help if you'd show the code you currently have, since otherwise we'd have to do the entire exercise just to show how one thing works. The solution depends on how you're solving the overall puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints. You can state that `Suspect1` has the same traits as `Suspect2` just by `Suspect1 = Suspect2`, and to find out whether any member of a list `Suspects` has the traits of `Suspect1` by `member(Suspect1, Suspects)`.

The usual way of handling a disjunction in Prolog is by introducing a predicate with two clauses. E.g., a predicate that checks whether a suspect has either a ring or a mac is

```
ring_or_mac(suspect(_, _, _, _, ring, _)).
ring_or_mac(suspect(_, _, _, _, mac, _)).
```

If you put these hints together in the right way, you have a solution to your problem.

Comment: Great, I was failing to do that first step correctly. It works just fine now. Thank you for the patience