# How can I search a list with the underscore variable? (Prolog)

Tags: list, prolog

here's my problem I receive various lists with the underscore variable in them (for example: [ _, _, A, _, _] or [ _,A, B, _, _]), and I need to search those lists for the values that matter (in this case A or A and B)

Is it even possible or am I trying to solve this the wrong way.

**For better context:** I'm trying to make a cluedo type program in **Prolog**, you have your clues, then you receive clues from other players and try to find the murderer, but I want one list for every suspect ( like this [name,age,weapon, personal item]), so as you can see every time you get a clue like a weapon I receive a list like this [ _, _, knife, _]

if anyone could help i would appreciate

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check whether a variable is still free is with the ISO predicates `var/1` and `nonvar/1`, which are true if their argument is a free variable or instantiated.

So, if you have a list with some variables bound, you can say:

```
nonvar_member(M, List) :- member(M, List), nonvar(M).
```

This predicate will enumerate (unify with *M* through backtracking) the elements of *List* which are not free variables:

```
?- nonvar_member(X, [2,_,_,3,A,1,_]).
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 1 ;
false.
```

But altogether there are many examples around (also on Stackoverflow) of using Prolog for solving puzzles based on clues, so try to look at those first.

Comment: member/2 should suffice for the typical usage. Using - and understanding - nonvar/1 will put the OP on a difficult track.

Comment: @CapelliC I must admit that I don't understand.... Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your explanation is sound, but IMHO nonvar/1 isn't appropriate, or even misleading.

Comment: @CapelliC :) apparently I am mislead myself, this is why I would like to know what is it that I am not getting, or how it should be done instead. My understanding of Prolog is right around mount stupid at the moment.... http://borgerlyst.dk/borgerlyst.dk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Mount-stupid-%E2%80%93-Borgerlyst.jpg

Comment: @CapelliC Or do you mean this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591868/or-procedure-in-prolog

Comment: @Boris I don't understand that either. :)

Comment: I think @CapelliC is just saying that `nonvar/1` leads to a complicated digression about ground and nonground terms which probably isn't necessary to solve this problem. I love the mount stupid graphic though... pretty sure I'm still climbing it...

Comment: Yes, as Daniel say, I thought was better to avoid complications. Maybe I misunderstood the question (I'm also applying to that fancy graphic :), seems about a 'zebra puzzle', usually member suffices.